# Syntax/code style/writing checking tool for Markdown files

Tags: markdown, static-analysis

Is there a static "code" analysis tool that can check the syntax of a Markdown file? It would also be great to have a tool that validates a Markdown file against certain rules such as, e.g., [Checkstyle](http://checkstyle.sourceforge.net/) does for Java and [Pylint](http://www.pylint.org/) for Python.

I want to have such a tool in order to perform basic checks on my documentation files.

Comment: AFAIK every character stream is valid markdown....

Comment: i would not consider "[stackoverflow]http://stackoverflow.com/)" to be valid, since the opening "(" is missing. But you are right, there is no clearly defined format (yet) and what seems like a syntax error could also have been intended.

Comment: Then you can't hope for a formal check.  At best you can hope for hueristics.   Why can't you define a set of regexps that detect style violations, and simply run that set against your text?

Comment: I would be okay if the program defined a formal grammar for a valid Markdown file, and then validated the file against it. Already now there are several flavors for Markdown files, so I guess there will be no silver bullet. Heuristics would also be okay. My mine concern is to have some quality checks that at least ensure that my Markdown files look similar. ;) I could define the regexps myself but then I would be the one writing the tool I am looking for.

Comment: @Clifford If you are unsure on what question can be asked on Stackoverflow, then please read the FAQ. I know how to write such a tool myself. However, developing such a tool is not only a one time effort but still takes time in maintaining and updating it - time I would rather spend on the main aspects of my projects.

Comment: @box : Clearly I am not the one confused.  This clearly comes under the "recommend a tool" off-topic category.  And as has been stated and you accept, anything that is not mark-up is valid plain text.  A markdown editor with preview ans used on SO perhaps is the best you can do.

Comment: @Clifford: 1. Sorry, I was not aware that a "Some questions are still off-topic, even if they fit into one of the categories listed above" list exists. I voted this question to be closed. I am surprised, since I often find such questions on Stackoverflow. Still, not all valid questions on Stackoverflow are about writing code as you implied.
2. It seems that no such tool exists yet. However, tools like Checkstyle, Pylint, or Findbugs also operate on valid source code. In my question I not only asked for syntax checking, but also some other kind of rule checking.

Comment: Off-topic questions in niche areas or tags may not get enough views to get closed, so of the millions of questions, there is bound to be some chaff.  Personally I would tolerate questions of this nature; I think it is marginal with respect or on or off topic and unlikely to attract opinionated "my favourite library" responses because there is no such library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Markdownlint](https://github.com/mivok/markdownlint) is a Ruby library which also contains a command line interface. There is also a [JavaScript/Node clone](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint) without the command line interface.

Answer (score 2):

In Markdown generally, and the [CommonMark](http://commonmark.org/) standard specifically, [all input is valid](http://talk.commonmark.org/t/specify-when-if-ever-parsers-should-give-up/969/9). For example the following is simply a paragraph with the text `[no]link)`:

```
[no]link)
```

I'm sure you could come up with some patterns to look out for an emit warnings for though. But since there are so many different styles of writing markdown, this hasn't been done. Personally, I find it enough to write in an editor with syntax highlighting, so things like `[no]link)` aren't highlighted as expected.

Comment: since it seems that no tools exist yet, i accept this answer.

Answer (score 1):

I use [markdownlint](https://github.com/DavidAnson/markdownlint) for rules and its [CLI version](https://github.com/igorshubovych/markdownlint-cli) as code analysis tool.

It is easy to install if you have Node Package Manager

```
npm install -g markdownlint-cli
```

Use it as

```
markdownlint *.md
```